# Prove that the vector space $V$ must be infinite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Suppose $V$ is a vector space and subspaces $U_1,U_2$ of $V$ are such that $U_1 \times U_2$ is isomorphic to $U_1+U_2$ but $U_1+U_2$ is not a direct sum. Prove that $V$ must be infinite dimensional.

**Attempt:** We are given that $\gamma:U_1\times U_2 \rightarrow U_1+U_2$ is an isomorphism.

Therefore, $\gamma$ is injective and surjective and thus for any $u_1+u_2 \in U_1+U_2,$ there exist a unique tuple $(u_1,u_2) \in U_1 \times U_2$

Then, $U_1+U_2$ should be a direct sum irrespective of whether $V$ is infinite-dimensional or not. ( since $\gamma$ is injective, for any $u_1+u_2 \in U_1+U_2$, there should exists a unique tuple $(u_1,u_2) \in U_1 \times U_2 \implies$ there's a unique way of expressing $u_1 +u_2 \implies U_! + U_2$ must be a direct sum )

Could someone please point-out where am I making a mistake? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> thus there's only $1$ unique way of expressing any vector in $U_1+U_2$.

This is vague.  You seem to be mixing up "1 unique way of expressing $y \in U_1 + U_2$ as $\gamma(x) = y$" with "1 unique way of expressing $y \in U_1 + U_2$ as $y = u_1 + u_2$ where $u_i \in U_i$."

That $\gamma$ is an isomorphism gives the former interpretation.  That $U_1+U_2$ is a direct sum requires the second interpretation.  Therefore, regardless of how you formalize that vague statement, you'll end up using an implication that is false.

---

With your new edit, you are begging the question when you say

> thus for any $u_1+u_2 \in U_1+U_2,$ there exist a unique tuple $(u_1,u_2) \in U_1 \times U_2$

This notation assumes you have $\gamma(u_1,u_2) = u_1+u_2,$ which is a pretty strong assumption (it in fact would imply $U_1+U_2$ is a direct sum).  Instead, all you have is that given any $u_1 + u_2 \in U_1 + U_2$, we have a unique $(v_1, v_2) \in U_1\times U_2$ such that $\gamma(v_1,v_2) = u_1+u_2.$

---

In answer to

> So, how do i bring the finiteness of $V$ come into the picture here?

Assuming $V$ is finite dimensional implies $U_1, U_2, U_1\times U_2, U_1+U_2$ are all finite dimensional.  Now consider $\gamma : U_1 \times U_2 \to U_1 +U_2$ defined by $\gamma(u_1,u_2) = u_1 + u_2.$  This is obviously a surjective linear map, and by using the rank-nullity theorem, we can show $\text{Nullity } \gamma = 0$, so $\gamma$ is an isomorphism and $U_1+U_2$ is a direct sum.

Comment: I have edited my query. If $\gamma$ is injective and surjective and thus for any $u_1+u_2 \in U_1+U_2,$ there exist a unique tuple $(u_1,u_2) \in U_1 \times U_2$

Comment: Isn't the injectivity and direct sum in the same context here?

Comment: @MathMan Well, it's no longer vague, but your notation is still trying to cheat, as you're assuming $U_1+U_2$ is a direct sum when you say "for any $u_1+u_2\in U_1+U_2$ there exist a unique $(u_1,u_2) \in U_1\times U_2$"

Comment: No. I meant that since $\gamma$ is injective, for any $u_1+u_2 \in U_1+U_2$, there should exists a unique tuple $(u_1,u_2) \in U_1 \times U_2 \implies$ there's a unique way of expressing $u_1 +u_2 \implies U_! + U_2$ must be a direct sum

Comment: @MathMan See my edit for a more extensive answer to why that notation doesn't work.

Comment: I see now what you mean there. So, how do i bring the  finiteness/ infiniteness of $V$ come into the picture here?

Comment: which also means, when $V$ is finite dimensional, then $v_1, v_2$ should be equal to $u_1, u_2$ . Am i correct?

Comment: @MathMan Well, we can't assume the isomorphism has that form, but from the isomorphism we can conclude the dimensions are equal, and then from that we can show your intended $\gamma$ is another isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have one more question please. What difference does it make when $V$ is infinite dimensional? ( in the later part of the answer you wrote ) . Thank you very much

Comment: @MathMan If $V$ has infinite dimension, then $U_1\times U_2, U_1+U_2$ can have infinite dimension and then the rank-nullity theorem doesn't allow you to solve for the nullity.  That is, it might have the form $$\infty = \infty + \text{Nullity }\gamma$$ from which we can conclude nothing about the nullity.

Comment: You used the rank-nullity theorem to show that $\dim null \gamma = 0$ But, that means, we already know that $\dim (U_1+U_2)= \dim U_1 + \dim U_2 .$ Isn't that a contradiction because this is possible only when it is already mentioned that it's a direct sum

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101140/discussion-between-brian-moehring-and-mathman).